# Entity Framework Core on top of an AWS Aurora PostgreSQL cluster with a write/read node and a read only node

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework-core, amazon-aurora

I have an API Gateway running .NET Core which proxies to AWS Lambda functions. Using Entity Framework Core, these Lambda functions communicate with an AWS Aurora PostgreSQL RDS Cluster. The cluster contains one read/write node and one read only node.

During setting up EF Core, I used database first to scaffold, which has worked fine. The scaffolding was done off the read/write instance of the cluster, and the read write instance is what is referenced in the context connection string in the resulting DatabaseContext class.

However, I have some read intensive API methods (and resulting Lambda functions) that I would like to point specifically to my read only node (which has sub-second replication from the read/write node managed automatically by AWS). I have no idea however, how to set this up in my EF Core implementation. I am a beginner with EF Core, so I've been really happy that I have it working with the one node. How do I set things up in my .NET Core application so I can specify some queries to go to the read only node? The read only node has exactly the same schema and objects.

If I try to do a database first scaffold using the db context scaffold via the EF Core CLI but point it to the read only node, will that work? Or fail miserably? Is there some kind of specific way I should be setting this up? Or should I avoid EF Core for the read only node, and just use something like Dapper or SqlKata to do the read only queries and maintain its own connections etc?

Comment: i have not used amazon RDS ever but i can try to give you pointer from Postgres side, is this a patroni setup or just replication between 2 postgres nodes ? and if so do you use some sort of load balancer to connect to the nodes or is there an ip assigned to them to connect?

Comment: This explains how the nodes are setup within AWS. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/Aurora.Overview.Endpoints.html#Aurora.Overview.Endpoints.Types I don't specify any load balancer etc, that's managed in AWS. I have 3 DNS names. A cluster DNS, a read/writer master DNS and a read only DNS. Replication between read/write and read happens automatically. My EF Core is scaffolded using the DNS of the read/write endpoint. I was hoping to introduce a read only scaffold/context for the read only endpoint for read intensive things like Search.

Answer (score 13):

Assuming your Context is named `DbContext` extend it like that:

```cs
public class RwDbContext : DbContext {}
public class RoDbContext : DbContext {}
```

And then, in `Startup.cs` register this contexts and point them to different connection strings:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<RwDbContext>(options => options.UseNpgsql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("RwDbContext")));
    services.AddDbContext<RoDbContext>(options => options.UseNpgsql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("RoDbContext")));
}
```

Also add the connection string to your `appsettings.json`:

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "RwDbContext": "Host=rwdb;...",
    "RoDbContext": "Host=rodb;..."
  }
}
```

Now you can use the `RoDbContext` for reading and `RwDbContext` for writing.

But when interacting with `dotnet ef` you have to use the `--context <DBCONTEXT>` option to point it to the R/W Context from now on.

Comment: Thank you so much. So I don't actually need to re-scaffold my RO instance? As the schema is exactly the same?

Comment: Ok, well this sounds perfect. I'll hopefully get a chance to test today, but sir or ma'am, the bounty be yours! *streamers* *confetti* Yay! :)

Comment: Glad if I could help. The bounty isnt the incentive for me. I just want more devs to use dot net core + postgres :)

Comment: Thanks Florian. This is my first time with either! I normally use SQL Server + SqlKata, but wanted to take advantage of AWS Aurora performance etc, so have gone with PostgreSQL and EF Core. So far finding it great, although PostgreSQL is a very different beast to SQL Server. :)

Comment: Yeah, they are quite different, I went through the same transition a couple of years back. But postgres has good documentation and a large community. Stackoverflow will help you out :)

Comment: Thanks so much Florian. If you feel like exchanging contact details that would be awesome, as I will no doubt get stuck on other PostgreSQL things over the next month as I build this platform. :)